# Jquery to switch between iframe and image

Tags: jquery

I wish to have a onclick button to switch between an iframe and an image.

How is this possible? Please show me with jsfiddle if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('iframe').toggle();
$('button').click(function(){
  $('img').toggle();
  $('iframe').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>toggle</button>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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
" />
<iframe src="https://google.com/"></iframe>
```